# In Linux kernel - is commenting out a line in .config file equal to set it to "=n"?

Tags: linux, kernel, configuration, kernel-modules

In the Linux kernel .config file, is setting a configuration to "n" having the same effect as commenting out the entire row?

```
for example:
CONFIG_TEST=n
and
# CONFIG_TEST
```

Answer (score 1):

No, commenting out the line with no other change is not equivalent to disabling the setting; if you have a `.config` with

```
# CONFIG_TEST
```

`make oldconfig` will ask you about it again, as will any attempt to build the kernel or part of it.

[The equivalent is](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.6/source/scripts/kconfig/confdata.c#L452)

```
# CONFIG_TEST is not set
```

Please heed the warning at the start of `.config`:

```
# Automatically generated file; DO NOT EDIT.
```

Comment: Correct, but sometimes, for sake of having a successful build, some configuration flags in the .config files are advised to be commented out. It did work for me when downloading a Kernel Source Tree, and when tried to build it on VM. It failed and when commenting out the attribute in the .config, it was built successfully. Hence, my question.

Comment: Could you give a specific example? `CONFIG_TEST` isn’t a configuration key in current kernels AFAICT.

Comment: Sure.
I'm running an Ubuntu VM which has a running kernel: 5.11.0-41-generic
I downloaded a local kernel tree: 5.15.6 (currently, it's the latest)
and placed the .config from the running kernel into my downloaded kernel tree.
When building it I got some errors, and in order to solve them I had to comment out:
# CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEY.  
# CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY.  
Also, I had to modify:
CONFIG_FRAME_WARN=0 (it was set 1024 before).  

and some additional changes like:
SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS="" (it had a string before).  
CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS="" (it had a string before).

Comment: is "# CONFIG_TEST=y" also equivalent with "# CONFIG_TEST is not set" ?

Comment: @Ted no, `# CONFIG_TEST=y` will cause the build to ask you whether to set `CONFIG_TEST` or not.